# MVVM design patterns using Polymer js

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to design complex web application using Polymer js with MVVM design pattern? If it's possible then how to separate Model,View,ViewModel,since in all polymer example we write CSS,Business logic,view into a single file.Is it possible to write those in a structured way?please explain with sample code